# How to start gen_server module many times

Tags: erlang, gen-server

In erlang, when I start gen_server module by start_link(A) which includes a parameter,I can't start it twice by changing A. On the console, it shows {error,{already started,<0.61.0>}}. How can I solve the problem? Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your `start_link` call looks something like this:

```
gen_server:start_link({local, foo}, bar, [], [])
```

That means, start a gen_server using `bar` as the callback module, and register the new process with the name `foo` on the local node.  If there is already a process named `foo`, you'll get the `already_started` error.

To start a gen_server without a registered name, thereby making it possible to start any number of them, just drop the first argument:

```
gen_server:start_link(bar, [], [])
```

Comment: If you want to named servers, you can use `{local, list_to_atom("foo" ++ integer_to_list(N))`